# dotnet run in VSCode not working, executin using Live Server extension does work

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, signalr

I'm trying to scaffold an ASP.NET Empty project with SignalR, and when executing using `dotnet run` I get a 404 error in the browser, even though this is the terminal output:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:5500
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\User\Desktop\sela\SignalR\SignalRScaffold\src\Scaffold
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

Yet, when I use Live Server extension for execution it works. It's my first time developing ASP.NET Core on VSCode, I only used it previously for front-end stuff.

What I tried:
-Navigating to the URL with the index.html file

-Matching port and IP in the launchsettings.json file to the one Live Server starts

-Changing from localhost to my local IP address

-Trying literally the same address which Live Server starts on, with dotnet run (again, via the launchsettings.json

It works, it's not like it doesn't work at all and I get a 404. It's just that live server does something that `dotnet run` doesn't. Same with just running it with F5 on VScode.

Comment: you can not use liveserver with a dotnet project, but you can run your app using watch command to automatically reRun your project in case anything changed. `dotnet watch run`

Comment: @AliReza Live Server is actually the only thing that's working if I'm trying to run the project, that's the issue. No dotnet commands work, not watch and not run, they all get me a 404 while Live Server gets me to the page.

Comment: so you have a routing problem. you should add your startup configuration to the post because probably you did not define any controller or routing to handle requests.

Comment: @AliReza you would be absolutely right, yet it still works with live server and not with dotnet run. If I had a routing issue, it wouldn't have worked either way. I don't have a controller or routing in place yet, I literally navigate to the index.html via typing to the URL.

Comment: live-server simply host a file/folder so you can access the file via browser but in dotnet static file don't be serve automatically. you should explicitly define what is your expectations. at least you need to use `app.UseStaticFiles()` to get access to your static HTML from an asp.net pipeline.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0